# difference between AGP memory ,shared graphics memory

Tags: graphics, 3d, directx, direct3d

i'm a little confused about AGP memory and shared graphics memory http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_graphics_memory 
what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but hopefully this may help you, AGP is a slot type like PCI that you can put a AGP GPU in or a AIMM (AGP Inline Memory Module).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AGP_Inline_Memory_Module
http://computer.howstuffworks.com/agp.htm

Shared graphics memory is a section of normal RAM (System Memory) that is used by the graphics card.